# CSS float and JS drag'n drop : how to drag only one element?

Tags: css, css-float, draggable

I created a little JS program, **without any library** (I musn't use one), which is able to make an element draggable and droppable. In fact, at the beginning it was writen using the CSS property `position` for each element which is draggable. The `position` property was assigned to `absolute` and it worked pretty well (you don't need I show you the JS functions to make an element draggable and droppable to help me, **but ask if you do** - just know that my JS functions modified the CSS's `top` and `left`).

**I'm going to explain my problem.** Recently, I wanted to change a bit my program by using the property `float`, assigned to `left` instead of `position : absolute`. I didn't modify my JS drag'n drop functions (in fact, a little : now I use `marginTop` and `marginLeft`).

Now when I drag an element at the left of another one (which is his brother, in the DOM hierarchy), **both move in the same horizontal directions**. And it is the problem.

Well, do you know why ? I tried to use `clear : both` but it didn't solve my problem.

## Code

Here is the minimal code which uses only HTML and CSS : just change the value of the first div's `margin-left` and you will see that the second moves. My program does it (dragging system).

https://jsfiddle.net/L81vayjn/

This fiddle allows you to have quickly a visual. It contains this code, and only this :

```
<div style="float : left; margin-left : 50px; margin-top : 0px;" id="1">
First div : please, modify my `margin-left` !
</div>

<div style="float : left; margin-left : 0px; margin-top : 50px;" id="2">
Second div
</div>
```

Comment: Code. We need to see your code.

Comment: @j08691 : I edited the OP, the code is now available. Edit : a `clear : left` seems to solve the problem BUT introduces a new one : a carriage-return.